# How to mimic required for select field

Tags: html, validation, select

I want to mimic required for select field too. The required field works for select field if the first option is empty. But still i cant see the box which says "please fill out this field"

Is there is a hack or a way i can add the required box to the select field similar like what we have for input field in html5

Comment: So you say you want to have a selectbox with no empty option and still getting the popup that says to fill out the form?

Comment: But isn't it already filled in by default? I don't really understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`required` attribute works well on `<select>`. If you want to force user to make a choice here, create an option with blank value ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PQMpe/1/)).

```
<select name="choice" required>
    <option value="">None</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

[image]

Comment: I know but i am using slelect2 plugin and he is not showing that